# Possible to prevent another pod in podspec?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

Anyone know if it is possible to specify in a podspec that you CANNOT have both a certain pod and another pod at the same time? Essentially the opposite of a dependency.. I have been looking all around online and havn't been able to find anything.

Facing a paradigm where I want one central pod that includes all the functionality. Or users could use 1 or more of the subset pods in conjunction. So I wanted to ban installing both the big pod and 1 or more of the subset pods in conjunction.

Is this possible? If so, how?